# error after farm solution deployed

Tags: 2010, development, farm-solution

after i deploy a farm solution to sharepoint 2010 web application i saw below error some times in browser what it is and how to solve this error,

> CS0042: Unexpected error creating debug information file
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bf3fce1a\adf83866 \App_GlobalResources.PDB' --
>
> 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\bf3fce1a\adf83866\App_GlobalResources.pdb:  The process
>   cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

[image]

here after i redeploy i got below error in visual studio

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id
>   '2227c19c-e944-438a-b769-e58d48181de8' is not installed in this farm,

Comment: did you try to fully retract the solution then re add, deploy and install it? also recycle the SharePoint timer service after retraction.

Comment: we have two wfe servers i removed the deployed solutions from admin/farsolutions page from central admin  and for add, deploy and install  can i use powershell ? if use powershell what are the commands?

Comment: when i deploy using install spsolution  i got error Install-SPSolution : This solution contains no resources scoped for a Web appli
cation and cannot be deployed to a particular Web application.

Comment: what command you are using?

Comment: Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "C:\wsp1\eServices123.wsp" and error when i run   Install-SPSolution -Identity "eServices123.wsp"   -AllWebApplications   -GACDeployment -CASPolicies

Comment: try without allwebapp and caspolices

Comment: remove the -AllWebApplications from the second command, if you are getting that error message your solution must be globally deployed - wops, double, Waqas preceded me by some seconds.